# Модификатор в БЭМ

Tags: бэм

Есть вопрос по БЭМу, хотел бы уточнить, как правильно работать с Модификатором, его нужно записывать только с названием Блока (button button_red) или можно записывать и отдельно (button_red)?

Comment: все зависит от того, что ты меняешь в модификаторе

Comment: Спасибо за ответ